# Spring Batch JdbcPagingItemReader seems not EXECUTING ALL THE ITEMS

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm working on an app that extract records from an Oracle database and then are exported as one single tabulated file.

However, when I attempt to read from the DB using JdbcPagingItemReader and write to a file I only get the number of records specified in pageSize. So if the pageSize is 10, then I get a file with 10 lines and the rest of the records seem to be ignored. So far, I haven't been able to find whats is really going on and any help would be most welcome.

Here is the JdbcPagingItemReader config:

```
<bean id="databaseItemReader"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTest" />
<property name="queryProvider">
  <bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTest" />
    <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT *" />
    <property name="fromClause" value="FROM *****" />
    <property name="whereClause" value="where snapshot_id=:name" />
    <property name="sortKey" value="snapshot_id" />
  </bean>
</property>
<property name="parameterValues">
   <map>
    <entry key="name" value="18596" />
   </map>
</property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="100000" />
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="com.mkyong.ViewRowMapper" />
</property>
```

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
<!-- write to this csv file -->
<property name="resource" value="file:cvs/report.csv" />
<property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

<property name="lineAggregator">
      <bean
       class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
    <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
    <property name="fieldExtractor">
          <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
        <property name="names" value="ID" />
       </bean>
    </property>
       </bean>  
</property>
```

```
  <job id="testJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
<step id="step1">
  <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="databaseItemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="1" />
  </tasklet>
</step>
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345157/spring-batch-jdbcpagingitemreader-seems-not-paginating?rq=1

Comment: no it's not the same they changed the use of the reader they have used finally jdbcCursorItemReader in my case i want absolutely to use the JdbcPagingItemReader for performance reasons

Comment: Try adding following property to your datasource bean "<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>"

Comment: And if possibel keep both pagesize and commit-interval same.If nothing works, then i would say to use  JdbcCursorItemReader which reads one by one..

Answer (score 2):

it was the  scope="step" that was missing it should be:

```
<bean id="databaseItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
```

Comment: See my comment below for java config

Answer (score 1):

Your setting seem incorrect for **whereClause and sort key can not be same** because pagesize works hand to hand with your sorting column name.

Check how is your data(in corresponding table) looks like.

In spring batch , as per your configuration, spring will create and execute as given below..
first query executed with pagesize = 10 , is like following

```
SELECT top 10  FROM tableName where snapshot_id=18596 snapshot_id > 10
```

Second /remaining query executed depends on your sort key.

```
SELECT *  FROM tableName  where snapshot_id=18596 snapshot_id > 10
SELECT *  FROM tableName  where snapshot_id=18596 snapshot_id > 20
```

and so on..  try running this query in database , doesn't it look weird . :-)

If you don't need where clause, remove it.

And if possible keep page size and commit-interval same, because that's how you decide to process and persist. But of course that depends on your design. So you decide.

Answer (score 0):

Adding @StepScope made my item reader take off with paging capability.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
ItemReader<Account> ItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[id]}") String id) {
    JdbcPagingItemReader<Account> databaseReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setPageSize(100);
    databaseReader.setFetchSize(100);
    PagingQueryProvider queryProvider = createQueryProvider(id);
    databaseReader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Account.class));
    return databaseReader;
}
```