# How to use fetch size in JdbcTemplate to process 20+ millions rows?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have table with 20+ millions of rows and I can't select all rows using single query because of `OutOfMemoryError`. I read about `fetchSize` attribute and looks like it might help to resolve my issue because it is common advise

But I have question about how to apply it.

I have following code:

```
private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
...
    jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(1000);
    List<MyTable> myList= this.jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT * FROM my_table",
                new Object[]{},
                MyTableMapper.INSTANCE
        );
    mylist.foreach(obj->processAndSave(obj));
```

Looks like jdbc driver will select 1000 per request. But what should I do to proceess all 20+ millions rows ?

Should I invoke `jdbcTemplate.query` several times ?

Comment: Why not basing on pagination?

Comment: @YCF_L  I thought that fetch size does smth like this. Is it false?

Comment: Collecting everything to a `List` will throw `OutOfMemoryError` regardless of fetch size set

Comment: hmm not exactly that, but you need to use limit and offset in your query, if you read the [doc about setFetchSize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize-int-) it doesn't work like you think

Comment: the question here, why you want to load 20M+ row in your code?

Comment: What you're doing is: execute this query and store all the results in a List in meory. Setting the fetch size won't change anything. The fetch size is useful to control how many rows are loaded at once when iterating through a ResultSet: insted of doing a network trip every time you ask for the next row in the result set, you can ask the driver to load and buffer, let's say, 100 rows in memory. When you are at the 101th row, a new network trip is made to load and buffer the 100 next rows.

Comment: If you want to process a very large number of rows, you need to make sure your driver doesn't load everything in memory (MySQL does that, and PostgreSQL does that by default, too). And thenyou need to iterator through the ResultSet, without trying to transform the whole resultset to a List.

Comment: Which RDBMS/driver are you using?

Comment: @JB Nizet, I use Postgres

Comment: @ YCF_L, what do yout think about https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298569/2674303 ?

Comment: @caco3  I don't need all rows in List but I need process each row

Comment: @JBNizet Please provide example

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html

Comment: @JB Nizet But I use spring JdbcTemplate in the project.So can I use org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#queryForRowSet(java.lang.String) and iterate over RowSet instead of ResultSet ?

Comment: You probably want to use a RowCallbackHandler: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler-

Comment: @JB Nizet, so I have to do 2 things: 1 - execute row processing inside RowCallbackHandler 2-set fetch size on jdbc template (for example 10_000)

Comment: @JB Nizet is it truth?

Comment: Yes. But why don't you just test it?

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks. I will do it. Just wanted to get your response

Comment: @JB Nizet I have a quiestion how to chosse correct fetch size.

Comment: @gstackoverflow if you don't ask it, I can't possibly answer it (and no one can)

Answer (score 0):

You can **Getting results based on a cursor**

If you are using PostgreSQL 11
requiments:

1. setFetchSize > 0
2. make sure autocommit is off

For you example for standard configurations

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.jdbc.template.fetch-size=50
```

Also if you want process the result ouside of a repository class
you can combine with queryForStream

```
Stream<MyTable> stream = jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(SQL,  MyTableMapper.INSTANCE);
```

> PostgreSQL Documentation:
> Issuing a Query and Processing the Result
>
> https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html